# Can't list files in documents with python (mac)

Tags: python

Hey I'm trying to list all the files in Documents (on a mac). In python I am using this code:

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("/Documents/"):
    print(file)
```

I keep getting the error `No such file or directory`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: there's no such directory. It's `/Users/<your user>/Documents` or `~/Documents`

Comment: Get to know OS X folder structure, e.g.: http://www.dummies.com/computers/macs/mac-operating-systems/basics-of-the-os-x-folder-structure/ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The folder is not `/Documents/`. `Documents` is below your home directory. Use:

```
for file in os.listdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Documents')):
    # your code here
```

Comment: do I omit the `listdir` when using this?

Comment: @KexAri no. `expanduser` just produces a new string where `~` is replace with your actual home directory.

Answer (score 1):

You should really give the absolute path, for Documents, it should be:

```
~/Documents or
/home/your-user-name/Documents
```